# Proper way to convert HEX to ASCII read from a file C++

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

In my code bellow `CODE 1` reading HEX from a file and storing in in string array won't convert it to `ASCII` when printed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // CODE 1
    std::ifstream input("C:\\test.txt"); // The test.txt contains \x48\x83\xEC\x28\x48\x83
    std::stringstream sstr;
    input >> sstr.rdbuf();

    std::string test = sstr.str();
    std::cout << "\nString from file: " << test;
    
    //char* lol = new char[test.size()];
    //memcpy(lol, test.data(), test.size());
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    // CODE 2
    std::string test_2 = "\x48\x83\xEC\x28\x48\x83";
    std::cout << "\n\nHardcoded string: " << test_2 << "\n";
    // Prints as ASCII "H(H" , which I want my CODE 1 to do.

}
```

In my `CODE 2` sample, same `HEX` is used and it prints it as `ASCII`. Why is it not the same for `CODE 1`?
[image]

Comment: Your string `test_2` never contains `\x48\x83\xEC\x28\x48\x83`, the C++ compiler already processed the escape sequences and put the resulting binary data into the `std::string` variable.  For input from a file, you'll have to process the escape sequences.

Comment: However, one questions why you are writing C++ character escape sequences to a text file in the first place, when you could use a HEX editor.  Then you would use the hex values when editing, and the resulting file would have the real binary data that your program wants.

Comment: The `\xNN` escape sequence only applies to string literals in code, not characters in memory or those read from file.

Comment: In C++ code, the following string literals are equivalent `"ABC"`, `"\x41\x42\x43"`, `"\0101\0102\0103"`, even `"A\x42\0103"`.  ASCII Text files are just text, no "escape sequence" grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it looks like there is some confusion. First, I have to ask if you're SURE you know what is in your file.

That is, does it contain, oh, it looks like about 20 characters:

```
\
x
4
8
```

et cetera?

Or does it contain a hex 48 (one byte), a hex 83 (one byte), for a total of 5-ish characters?

I bet it's the first. I bet your file is about 20 characters long and literally contains the string that's getting printed.

And if so, then the code is doing what you expect. It's reading a line of text and writing it back out. If you want it to actually interpret it like the compiler does, then you're going to have to do the steps yourself.

Now, if it actually contains the hex characters (but I bet it doesn't), then that's a little different problem, and we'll have to look at that. But I think you just have a string of characters that includes `\x` in it. And reading / writing that isn't going to automatically do some magic for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes the file contains the HEX value as a string just like it prints it out. Which means I am doing it wrong. I've been trying to figure out how to read it or convert it correctly so it prints it as ASCII

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure you understand what you are saying when you say it contains HEX values. How long is the file? About 20 bytes? Then NO, it doesn't contain HEX values. It contains ASCII characters. If it's about 5 or 6 bytes, then C++ isn't going to print it the way you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

When you read from file, the backslash characters are not escaped. Your `test` string from file is literally an array of chars: `{'\\', 'x', '4', '8', ... }`

Whereas your hardcoded literal string, `"\x48\x83\xEC\x28\x48\x83";` is fully hex escaped by the compiler.

If you really want to store your data as a text file as a series of "backslash x NN" sequences, you'll need to convert after you read from file.  Here's a hacked up loop that would do it for you.

```
std::string test = sstr.str();

char temp[3] = {};
size_t t = 0;
std::string corrected;

for (char c : test)
{
   if (isxdigit(c))
   {
       temp[t] = c;
       t++;
       if (t == 2)
       {
          t = 0;
          unsigned char uc = (unsigned char)strtoul(tmp, nullptr, 16);
          corrected += (char)uc;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you. I tested it your code and from that file I get printed out `HHHHHHHHHHHHH(H(H(H(H(HH(HH(HH(HH(H` which seems a lot longer than it should be

Comment: If you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the returned string in `\x` then make casting from string to int,
finally casting to char.

this resource will be helpful

[strtok](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstring/strtok) And [convert](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-cpp)

Comment: I could read the file as `4883EC284883` instead of stripping the `\x` and then cast it? maybe its easier?

Comment: no you need each string to be casting from string to int, then casting to charecter Ex: `"48"` to 48 then casting it with char to be `zero char`